# Need some assistance with anacron in Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 I try to learn about using `anacron`. And there're 3 things so far that I can't understand. Please explain!

1. WHEN is the `anacron` command (tast) executed for the FIRST TIME?
   Let's say today is Wednesday 2 p.m. (14:00) and I've just made a new weekly task for `anacron`. So when should I be expecting the first execution of it? In other words, what's the starting point here? Weekly, starting from...???
2. Let's say I've got 3 commands. So this MUST be a script OR... I can stuff all three commands in ONE single `anacron` task? To be more specific, I want to stop the process, delete the file's content and then to re-start the same stopped process.
3. Where should I put the commands for `anacron`? They say that in `/etc/anacrontab`, but there I see 3 default lines of commands that govern the `cron` (if I understand that correctly). Should I write my own commands in the same place just below those three?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to realise is that `anacron` is designed to complement `cron`; you should really just configure jobs in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` or `/etc/cron.monthly`. `anacron` is not designed for jobs that run more frequently; its main purpose is to allow daily, weekly or monthly jobs to "catch up" on computers which aren't on all the time.

1. `anacron` uses timestamps and the time elapsed since the last execution to decide whether to run a job. If you declare a weekly job, *i.e.* one with a delay of seven days, `anacron` will run it whenever it detects that it hasn't been run for seven days. So when you create a new job, it should run it the next time it is invoked; by default this is either the next time the system is rebooted, the next time its power status changes (from battery to AC), or at 3am.
2. Create a script with the three commands and drop it in `/etc/cron.daily` (or `.weekly` or `.monthly`, as appropriate).
3. As indicated above, you should just use `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly,monthly}`. You can use `/etc/anacrontab` if you want but that's not the intended use.

See the [Debian/Ubuntu-specific documentation](http://sources.debian.net/src/anacron/2.3-23/debian/README.debian/) and the [`anacron` README](http://sources.debian.net/src/anacron/2.3-23/README/) for more details.